# How to get a specific element from a collection of lists?

Tags: java, list, collections

I have a list myCollection which is a collection of lists like

```
myCollection = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
```

Iterating this list and by get(i) method i will get a particular sublist.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myCollection.size(); i++) {
      System.out.println(myCollection.get(i));
}
```

I tried creating a new list for the sublist and iterating it but i am getting the complete list as `[1,2,3,4]`

```
for (int i = 0; i < myCollection.size(); i++) {
    List list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(myCollection.get(i));
       for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
        System.out.println("list.get(j) -- "+list.get(j).toString());
     }    
}
```

how to get the element in this sublist ?

Thanks

Comment: you're creating the `List list` on every iteration of the `for` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myCollection.size(); i++) 
{     
    List myList = myCollection.get(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < myList.size(); j++) 
    {
        System.out.println("myList.get(j) -- "+myList.get(j).toString());      
    }
}
```

What you are doing is:

```
list.add(myCollection.get(i));
```

this line will add the complete list at index `i` to the `list`. So, no need to add it to another list. simply store it in a myList variable, as I did. and then iterate.

Comment: thanks a lot :) It's working as i was expecting. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
list.get(i).get(j)
```

Comment: the problem here is for the first array i will get the length as 1 and for the secong as 2 and so on.. and hence not able to get all the elements present in the first list. Say i have 3 elements then i am getting 1 element in the first array, 2 elements in the 2 array and all the elements in the 3 array. :(

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try something like this:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < myCollection.size(); i++) {
    list.add(myCollection.get(i));

}
```

Its also better to separate your printer:

```
for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
        System.out.println("list.get(j) -- "+list.get(j).toString());
     }
```

Comment: actually i am trying to build a logic to insert  large chunk of data dynamically using prepared statement. If i separate the for statements then it won't work for me. :( thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `list` because, you are storing a `list` in your List.

Also, you have declared a `raw type` list, which is not a good practice.

**You can rather get the individual elements from each nested list using enhanced-for loop: -**

```
myCollection = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]

for(List<Integer> list: myCollection) {

    for (Integer intVal: list) {
         System.out.print(intVal + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: `myCollection.get(i)` won't return `Integer` instead a `List` (or an array), check the first part of OP question.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Please read my post clearly. I told him to declare your `List` like that, and he will know where he is wrong..